# Question about natural language processing

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a graduation project related to "Aspect extraction (AE)".

I'm pretty confused about POS taging, syntax tree, grammar rules, and other low-level NLP stuff. I need a reference that teaches me these things in detail, so if any of you know I hope you don't mind me?

I know my question is not about programming directly and this may not agree with the site, but I really need to.

Comment: You can start from a resource like the following: https://github.com/chandanverma07/Ebooks/blob/master/Natural%20Language%20Processing%20with%20Python.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an easy one! I assume that you are trying to understand the underlying 'why' and 'what', so, if I were you I would start with the one and only "Speech and Language Processing" by Daniel Jurafsky and James H. Martin. They have a whole section (Section 17 in my Second edition) on the representation of meaning, and state representation, with a whole subsection on Aspect.
In addition to that, the book will also help you understand various existing approaches to POS-tagging and the other topics you mentioned above, and, the book is available online for free! There is even the draft of [the 3rd edition](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/ed3book.pdf) out there.
Additionally, after reading the chapters above, you can check out how other people do aspect extraction [here](https://paperswithcode.com/task/aspect-extraction/codeless)